# orderBy two fields (one in reverse)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to order a friend list by status (online firsts, offline lasts) and by alphabetical order. All I manage to get is:

- Online firsts / Reversed alphabetical order
- Or offline firsts / Alphabetical order

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vZzhIp4UdIM7itRLtTvu?p=preview) to expose my problem

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Change the `orderBy` filter to this:

```
orderBy:['-status','name']
```

This will order by descending status (by prefixing the `-` character), then ascending name. Currently you're passing `true` to reverse the sort, which is causing the status to be correct (online first), but the names to be reversed (i.e., descending).

If you want to keep the reverse boolean, you could use `orderBy:['status','-name']:true` but that seems less clear than just making `status` descending as shown earlier.

Comment: I did not see it, but it was in documentation at this page http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy

Comment: what if I'm using a model to sort?
for example:
`<input type="text"  ng-model="sort"/>`


`<div ng-repeat="review in reviews | orderBy:['-date', sort]">...</div>`

I can't make it work

Comment: Indeed, the documentation is there; I hadn't noticed it at all (it's technically covered in the Arguments section for others who might be looking). I suppose I should know better than to assume the examples in the Angular doc are representative. For bonus fun, note that Angular will apparently eval whatever strings you give it, so in addition to being able to pass a function, string, or array, you can just stick some JS in a string and it'll (probably, maybe) get run (at some point, somehow).

Comment: @carloscarcamo If your model is coming from a select directive, then it is a string that must be converted into an array.  Change your model to just "-date,sortItem", then do orderby:sort.split(",")

Answer (score 0):

There is another option to do that, you can have multiple orderBy filter in ng-repeat and that line :

```
<li class="friend" ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:['status','name']:true">
```

will be :

```
<li class="friend" ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'name':false | orderBy:'status':true">
```

The last orderBy is execute first and the second to last etc ...

Here is my plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/girPFzdi3Zx0yp0ASGVQ?p=preview

Comment: That's completly wrong! If you do this you get the list of friends ordered only by the last filter, and furthermore, the order has to be computed twice, what is quite silly...

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 1.5.8 previous example does not work.
Different logic has to be applied.

It looks logic from previous orderBy is applied to the next one, so in order to sort name ASC and status DESC name order has to be reveresed:

```
<li class="friend" ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'name':true | orderBy:'status':true">
```

Here is fixed example: http://plnkr.co/edit/0ZFIftSgNkU9F03xJztG?p=preview

Comment: That's completly wrong! If you do this you get the list of friends ordered only by the last filter, and furthermore, the order has to be computed twice, what is quite silly...

Comment: With all due respect Vi100, I've provided working example on plunker. Please take a look at it. If you have solution, please provide an example. We are here to help each other, not just to say it is wrong and silly without arguments provided.

Comment: Dont't you see that the results are ONLY ordered by the last of the two filters ("status" on your Plunker)??? Or maybe you don't understand what it means to order by TWO fields... It means ordering by the first one and when you get a duplicated value then use the second field to disambiguate.