# How can I order by more than one element with an angular ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I know how to do a simple orderBy like this:

```
ng-repeat="test in tes.tests orderBy: 'modifiedDate'">
```

but how can I orderBy: title (Ascending) and then modifiedBy (most recent first?

Comment: Array: `[+'modifiedDate', '-another']`

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290238/orderby-two-fields-one-in-reverse

Comment: @AlonEitan - Can you explain a bit more or maybe give an answer that shows this.  Should I just substitute 'modifedBy' with your answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
ng-repeat="test in tes.tests | orderBy:['+title','-modifiedDate']
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can.

```
<div ng-repeat="test in tes.tests | orderBy: ['title','-modifiedDate']"> {{title}} - {{modifiedDate}}  </div>
```